# matplotlib: plot a histogram from data

Tags: python, file, matplotlib, histogram

I have data (a spectrum) that I want to plot as a histogram.
I import the data and `spectrum.shape` shows me (1024,) as the format,
however `plt.hist` does not plot the data correctly.
If I use `plt.bar(...)` it works just fine, but for aesthetic reasons (I want to use the "stepfilled" histogram design) and I have to employ `plt.hist` which offers this option.
I really don't know what to do.
Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

spectrum = np.loadtxt('3000.mp',  skiprows=53)

y1=spectrum[:]
num_bins = 1024
diagram = plt.hist(y1, num_bins, alpha=0.5)
plt.xlabel("TOF / $\mu$s")
plt.ylabel("# ions")
plt.show()
```

I hope for your help.

Comment: Sorry if I have misinterpreted, but I think you need to read up on what a histogram will do for you.  As it seems that you might already have the counts in the data you read in (I am making this assumption based on the fact that you say that the number of samples is 1024, and you then define 1024 bins).  This is likely why bar is working and histogram isn't.

Comment: You just need to use the correct style arguments to `bar`, or look at how `hist` does the `stepfilled` plotting: https://github.com/tacaswell/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L5340 or use `step` + `fill_between`

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. i am employing bar now and it also looks quite nice;)

Answer (score 0):

I am interested also in this answer. Would you share how did you get the stepfilled design with bars?

Myself I am looking for something like this:

[image]

(this image comes from http://astroplotlib.stsci.edu/page_histograms.htm)

But I do not manage to generate it easily with a spectrum as an input.

Comment: Ideally, you should ask this as a separate question, rather than an answer.  However, the function in matplotlib that you're looking for is called `step`. http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.step http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/step_demo.html

Comment: i ended up not using the stepfilled command on plt.bar but just filled since i didnt get it to work...